# Python Looping in and out of def doesn't have the same result

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get some results of variables and insert them into a pandas Dataframe. I am getting some data from the Merchant API from Google and I want to write them into a pandas DataFrame. 
Initially I am executing calls to the APIs and then use **while ... continue** to reiterate over the loop and take the next page's results.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import httplib2
import pandas as pd

def get_products(merchant_id):

    request = service.products().list(merchantId=merchant_id,
                                          maxResults=250)

    while request is not None:
        result = request.execute()
        for product in result['resources']:
            product_id = product['id']
            availability = product['availability']
            category = product['productType'].split('>')
            category = category[0]
            return product_id,availability,category

        request = service.products().list_next(request, result)
        continue

if __name__ == '__main__':

    result = get_products('yyyy')
    print result
    data = {'product_id': result[0], 'availability': result[1], 'category': result[2]}

    products_df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=[0])
    print products_df
```

However in my output DataFrame I get only one line for some reason..

```
(u'online:CH:480089', u'in stock', u'Spielzeug ')
```

When I test in the defined function I have thousands of rows.

Do you see something wrong in my logic?

Comment: `continue` doesn't do anything as you've used it. the default is to continue.

Comment: You are `return`ing in your loop. So the function stops as soon as you reach `return`, it returns the single `product_id, availablility, category` tuple. You probably want to accumulate that in something like a `list` and return *that*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripping out all of the other statements and keeping just the important bits:

```
def get_products(merchant_id):
    while request is not None:
        for product in result['resources']:
            return product_id,availability,category  # The first product will be returned by the function
        continue  # essentially a NOP
```

You loop through the request and return the first product you find. You need to aggregate the results and then return that aggregation:

```
def get_products(merchant_id):
    result = []
    while request is not None:
        for product in result['resources']:
            result.append((product_id,availability,category))
    return result
```

which will return a list of tuples for every product... although take note your `data = {}` will not work with this format.